# Existing nodes to node group

Tags: node-editor

I've searched for a low level way (non "bpy.ops") to accomplish this task but there seems to be no possible way to get pre existing material nodes into a node group. I thought about running a loop over a material to populate a new node group with that material's nodes (attempting to copy the type and settings for each node) but considering the possibilities that could get a little cumbersome.

EDIT: I'm marking this thread closed due to inactivity. Probably a better approach was needed.

Comment: Could you add more information about what exactly are you trying to achieve?